# python shallow copy result is unexpected

Tags: python

```
import copy

lst = [1,2,3]

#shallow copy
s_copy = copy.copy(lst)
print('shallow copy: {}'.format(s_copy))
# prints [1,2,3]

# operation on this copy data 
s_copy[1]=123
print('Shallow copy after update: {}'.format(s_copy))
# prints [1,123,3]
print('Original list : {}'.format(lst))
# prints [1,2,3]
```

As per documentation, copy.copy creates a shallow copy where both list points to same data, when i assign new value to copied list, it changes only in new list. I know it is because these two objects are different and shares only values. Is that means shallow copy shares values as long as both are referring to same value and the moment value of new list changes, it points to new value in new list.

Comment: Where did you find that `where both list points to same data` ?

Comment: This is exactly how a shallow copy is supposed to work. Both lists contain the same objects (they weren't copied), but they are **different lists**.

Comment: Try doing the same with `lst = [1, [2], 3]` but then doing `s_copy[1][0] = 4` to see the difference

Comment: @Tomerikoo That way i can see the difference but i wanted to understand what is happening in my example. When i update value to copied list why only new list is getting changed. But when i follow your mention list, it changes both, why?

Comment: Read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#module-copy), there is a clear distinction between *shallow* and *deep* copy

Comment: I don't understand why this surprises you, the idea of doing a copy is to be able to change the list without affecting the original

Comment: @Raj because **they are different lists that contain the same objects**. If you modify the list, of course the lists changes. If you modify the object inside the list, of course, both lists will see that change, since *they both have the same objects*

Comment: To continue on that point, even if the list would be `lst = [1, [2], 3]` but still doing `lst[1], = 2` that will not affect the original as you're simply modifying the copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shallow copy means a copy of top level items only. Deeper levels stay referenced. Look:

```py
import copy
l1 = [1, 2, [3, 4]]
l2 = copy.copy(l1)
l2[2][1] = 5
print(l1)
# gives [1, 2, [3, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

In this content `shallow copy` means that objects inside original object still points to the same data for example:

```
In [1]: import copy

In [2]: orig_l = [1, [2, 3], 4]

In [3]: copy_l = copy.copy(orig_l)

In [4]: copy_l[1][0] = 5

In [5]: orig_l
Out[5]: [1, [5, 3], 4]

In [6]: copy_l
Out[6]: [1, [5, 3], 4]
```

and if you update the first level that changes will be implemented only to the child

```
In [7]: copy_l[2] = 44

In [8]: orig_l
Out[8]: [1, [5, 3], 4]

In [9]: copy_l
Out[9]: [1, [5, 3], 44]
```